# Is there a way to load an icon from a memory file handler?

Tags: c++, icons, wxwidgets

I am writing wxWidgets application where I am importing the .ICO file as a header.  I am attempting to use a wxMemoryFSHandler to make this icon (and others as well) accessible as files.  I am using the following code to do this:

```
wxFileSystem::AddHandler(new wxMemoryFSHandler);
wxMemoryFSHandler::AddFileWithMimeType(
   "app_inactive.ico",
   CsiWebAdmin_ico,
   sizeof(CsiWebAdmin_ico),
   "image/vnd.microsoft.icon");
```

Unfortunately, if I try to load an icon from this "file" as shown below, it does not work.  As I stepped through the MSW source (wx 2.8.10), I can see that the loader never attempted to resolve the virtual file name.

```
wxIcon icon("memory:app_inactive.ico");
```

I have also tried the following:

```
wxIcon icon(wxIconLocation("memory:app_inactive.ico"));
```

and have encountered the same results.

I realise that I can use resources to load these files but I would still face the same dilemma when the time came to port my application to GTK.  Is there something obvious that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have determined that there was no means of loading the icon set directly from the virtual file system.  I have figured out, however, a means to do so as follows:

```
wxFileSystem file_system;
Csi::SharedPtr<wxFSFile> ico_file(
   file_system.OpenFile(
      make_wxString(config->get_control()->get_attr_wstr(L"icon"))));
if(ico_file != 0)
{
   wxIconBundle icons;
   wxInputStream *stream(ico_file->GetStream());
   size_t image_count(wxImage::GetImageCount(*stream, wxBITMAP_TYPE_ICO));
   wxImage image;
   for(size_t i = 0; i < image_count; ++i)
   {
      if(image.LoadFile(*stream, wxBITMAP_TYPE_ICO, i))
      {
         wxIcon icon;
         icon.CopyFromBitmap(wxBitmap(image));
         icons.AddIcon(icon);
      }
   }
   SetIcons(icons);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to set application icons? Then see wxIconBundle. I use this piece of code:

```
    wxFileName frameIconFile = your_resources_folder;
    frameIconFile.SetFullName("appicon.ico");
    wxIconBundle frameIcons(frameIconFile.GetFullPath(),wxBITMAP_TYPE_ICO);
    mainFrame->SetIcons(frameIcons);
```

The icon bundle (it's a file with multiple icons) is loaded at application startup.
To build the icon bundle I use IcoFX (http://icofx.ro/).

Comment: I would prefer to avoid loading application resources from an external file.  However, I was going to convert the .ico file into a sequence of XPM files that could be compiled into the application and loaded into a wxIconBundle that way.

Answer (score 0):

See png2wx.pl for an example of how to embed icons into an executable; it is then available as a C symbol, such as

```
wxMenuItem *w = some_menu->Append(id, _("text"));
w->SetBitmap(*_img_exit_icon);
```

Comment: This doesn't really address the question.  My real question was why an icon can't be loaded from a virtual file system.